# Overlay histogram and histogram border in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to overlay a histogram border over the histogram, but they're not in the right location

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")

iris %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(Sepal.Length)
  ) +
  geom_histogram(
    alpha = .5
  ) +
  stat_bin(geom="step") +
  facet_wrap(
    ~Species, ncol = 1
  )
```

returns

[image]

How do I align the border with the histogram?

Comment: If you use `geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, color = "blue")`, does that do what you are asking for (I only added the `color = "blue"`.

Comment: @steveb -- no, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: My suggestion forgot to add that you should drop the `stat_bin("step")`, that will give you the border around the histogram boxes w/o trying to use a step function. I need a clarification, are you just trying to put a border on the boxes or shift the stat_bin ?

Comment: I want a single border outside the entire distribution, not a separate border on each bar in the histogram. that is, to shift the steps left.

Comment: Ok, now I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be done by specifying the `binwidth` and then setting the `breaks`

```
library(tidyverse)
data("iris")

iris %>% 
  ggplot( aes(Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = .5, binwidth = .1) +
  stat_bin(geom="step", breaks = seq(3,8, .1)) +
  facet_wrap( ~Species, ncol = 1)
```

[image]